# car died while driving, and now the engine will not turn over

Tags: engine, hyundai

My 2000 Hyundai Tibrun died while I was driving and now the engine will not turn over. The battery has a good charge still, its acting like the starter or the engine has frozen. The car spewed a bunch of oil out on the road where it died.

Could the headgasket have gone out and caused the engine to seize up? I have checked the oil level and it appears to be milky. I'm not sure of where to go from here or what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

head gasket seems likely considering the milky appearance of the oil. All hyundais have interference engines also, so if the timing belt failed while it was running the pistons will strike the valves in the cylinder head basically destroying the engine in most cases.

Comment: Where did the timing belt bit come from?